# Getting number copies of an object touching each other on a 2D plane (Java algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, plot

I need to write some code for a method that will return the number of objects that are touching each other for a java project i'm working on. This can be kind of hard to wrap your head around so here is a visual example.

[image: 2D Plane Example]

Where the light grey square is the Start, (that needs to be able to be any of the squares), and any square that is colored is a copy of the exact same object(Same code); I need to be able to find the amount of squares in any given pattern, as long as they are touching another one. This one would return 42, if i counted right, because that's the number of colored squares. 
I have access to methods that that will check for blocks above, below, and to either side of the block and will return a Boolean, but they can only see 1 above, 1 below, and 1 two each side . I think it needs to set off some kind of chain reaction. Where the other blocks check 1 above, below, and to the sides of themselves. Specifically this will be written in java, but is more of an algorithm/math question.

Comment: this is a nice problem!
You have to add a boolean field to the "square" object that indicates if it has been counted in the current algorithm execution. Then check recursively in every direction until you find a counted square or a wall. Think of it, almost, like a 4-tree with many cross connections.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Something like a flood-fill should work.

Comment: @Danstahr I think this may be a little complex for what im doing and i can foresee some problems with how things are saved, but i will try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create two lists - you can call them open and closed.
Add the start square to the open list.
While the open list is not empty:
  Remove one of the objects from the open list.
  Add this object to the closed list.
  For each of the 4 addjacent squares to this object:
    If the square is not in the open or closed lists and is the type you are trying to find add this square to the open list.
The size of the closed list is your answer.
```

Since you appear to be storing many references to the same object on you plane instead of different objects at each location, checking the lists to see if the object is already in them will not work.

One workaround for this is to replace the lists with two boolean arrays the size of your plane, and instead of adding or removing objects from a list flip the value of the boolean at the same location as the square you are processing to true or false.

Another way would be to create different objects for each grid location and give them another variable to tell if they are the type you are looking for, instead of looking for the same object.

A third way is to add an object which represents a plane position to the lists instead of adding the object you have found at that position.

Comment: Very good answer. This is breadth-first search. I suggest using a HashSet or a 2D boolean array rather than a list for the closed list, since you only need to be able to check whether it has been processed before.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer. I will try to get this implemented, if i have any problems i might report back, but this looks very doable and efficient!

Comment: I tried this, and it is not working. It is not working because all of my squares are the **same** object. Therefore when it checks to see if the square is there, the check fails because it is already in the list. Do you know of any workaround? I really enjoy the compact and simple nature of this solution. Edit- It is the same object because it is only created once by the project. I think i need to move the code to something that is created for each.

Comment: @user3311827 I've updated my answer, please tell me if anything is unclear or my solution still does not work.